# How to show 3 items one time - array

Tags: php

```
$urls = array("http://google.com" ,"http://hotmail.com" ,"http://yahoo.com" ,"http://stackoverflow.com" ,"http://bing.com" ,"http://cnn.com" ); 

$text = array("Google" ,"Hotmail" ,"Yahoo" ,"Stackoverflow" ,"Bing" ,"CNN"); 
        srand(time()); 

        $random = (rand()%3); 
echo ("<a href = \"$urls[$random]\">$text[$random]</a>");
```

Above will do this:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
```

How to show 3 links for example Yahoo, Google, Bing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the same element of the array. A function should suffice for this

```
function showLink(Array $url, Array $title, $position) {
    return '<a href = "' . $url[$position] . '">' . $title[$position] . '</a>';
}

echo $showLink($urls, $text, mt_rand(0, count($urls) -1);
```